# Doctrine 2 Class Table Inheritance YML

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, class-table-inheritance

I'm trying to use Class Table Inheritance within ZF2 and Doctrine 2.  My implementation is pretty simple.  I think I have the class structure all set, but I think there might be a problem with some setup somewhere.  Unfortunately, I have found a lot of documentation on the Class setup, but not a whole lot on the YML implementation.  Everyone seems to resort to using the doctrine tools to generate everything.  With how things are set up, using the doctrine tools is a little problematic, especially when using ZF2.  Also, I consider this to be a learning opportunity.  So, here is what I have:

The Current Problem:  I'm not getting any of the data from the child class/table:

```
.array(1) {
[0] =>
class MyCompany\Domain\Model\Customer\CustomerNote#2852 (9) {
  protected $customer =>
  NULL
  protected $note =>
  string(13) "Clever Note 1"
  protected $id =>
  string(1) "1"
  protected $disabled =>
  NULL
  protected $modified =>
  class DateTime#2884 (3) {

    ...
```

The Generic Notes Class/Table:

```
CREATE TABLE generic_notes
(
  note_id serial NOT NULL,
  discriminator character varying(255) NOT NULL, 
  note text,
  created timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  created_by_id bigint NOT NULL,
  modified timestamp with time zone,
  modified_by_id bigint,
  disabled timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT 'infinity'::timestamp with time zone,
  CONSTRAINT generic_notes_pkey PRIMARY KEY (note_id),
  CONSTRAINT generic_notes_created_by_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (created_by_id)
      REFERENCES users (user_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE 
      ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT generic_notes_modified_by_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (modified_by_id)
      REFERENCES users (user_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE 
      ON DELETE RESTRICT
)
```

The Customer Notes Class/Table (Inherits Generic Notes):

```
CREATE TABLE customer_notes
(
  note_id bigint NOT NULL,
  customer_id bigint NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT customer_notes_pkey PRIMARY KEY (note_id),
  CONSTRAINT customer_notes_note_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (note_id)
      REFERENCES generic_notes (note_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE RESTRICT 
      ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT customer_notes_customer_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (customer_id)
      REFERENCES customers (customer_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE R1ESTRICT 
      ON DELETE RESTRICT
)
```

YML Mapping for Note:

```
MyCompany\Domain\Model\Note:
  type: entity
  table: generic_notes
  inheritanceType: JOINED
  discriminatorColumn:
    name: discriminator
    type: string
    length: 255
  discriminatorMap:
    customer: MyCompany\Domain\Model\Customer\CustomerNote
  id:
    id:
      column: note_id
      type: bigint
      generator:
        strategy: IDENTITY
  fields:
    note:
      type: text
      nullable: true
    created:
      type: datetimetz
    modified:
      type: datetimetz
      nullable: true
    disabled:
      type: datetimetz
      nullable: true
  manyToOne:
    createdBy:
      targetEntity: MyCompany\Domain\Model\User
      joinColumn:
        name: created_by_id
        referencedColumnName: user_id
    modifiedBy:
      targetEntity: MyCompany\Domain\Model\User
      joinColumn:
        name: modified_by_id
        referencedColumnName: user_id
```

Customer Note Mapping:

```
MyCompany\Domain\Model\Customer\CustomerNote:
  type: entity
  table: customer_notes
  manyToOne:
    customer:
      targetEntity: MyCompany\Domain\Model\Customer
      inversedBy: customerNote
      joinColumn:
        name: customer_id
        referencedColumnName: customer_id
```

Generic Note Entity

```
<?php

namespace MyCompany\Domain\Model;

use MyCompany\Domain\Model\Entity\AbstractEntity;
use MyCompany\Domain\Model\Entity\DisabledTrait;
use MyCompany\Domain\Model\Entity\TimestampedInterface;
use MyCompany\Domain\Model\Entity\TimestampedTrait;

/**
 * Class Note
 *
 * @package MyCompany\Domain\Model
 */

class Note extends AbstractEntity implements TimestampedInterface
{
    use DisabledTrait;
    use TimestampedTrait;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $note;

    /**
     * @param string $note
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setNote($note)
    {
        $this->note = $note;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNote()
    {
        return $this->note;
    }
}
```

Customer Note Entity:

```
<?php

namespace MyCompany\Domain\Model\Customer;

use MyCompany\Domain\Model\Note;
use MyCompany\Domain\Model\Customer;

/**
 * Class CustomerNote
 * @package MyCompany\Domain\Model\Customer
 */
class CustomerNote extends Note
{
    /**
     * @var \MyCompany\Domain\Model\Customer
     */
    protected $customer;

    /**
     * @param \MyCompany\Domain\Model\Customer $customer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setCustomer(Customer $customer)
    {
        $this->customer = $customer;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return \MyCompany\Domain\Model\Customer
     */
    public function getCustomer()
    {
        return $this->customer;
    }
}
```

Generic Note Fixture Data:

```
generic_notes:
  -
    note_id: 1
    discriminator: customer
    note: Clever Note 1
    created: "2012-01-23 05:43:21.000000"
    created_by_id: 1
    modified: "2012-01-24 05:43:21.000000"
    modified_by_id: 2
    disabled: null
```

Customer Notes Fixture Data:

```
customer_notes:
  -
    note_id: 1
    customer_id: 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything above is perfectly valid and working. It appears that I wasn't including my notes fixture data for the customer notes unit test, and vice-versa. So, a number of days down the hole for my own stupidity.